# Accumulo Tablet Server doesn't utilize all available resources on host machine

Tags: accumulo

I have an Accumulo 1.8.1 cluster made by 12 bare metal servers.

**Cluster Configuration:**

Each server has 256GB of Ram and 2 x 10 cores CPU.

2 machines are used as masters (running HDFS NameNodes, Accumulo Master and Monitor). The other 10 machines has 12 Disks of 1 TB (11 used by HDFS DataNode process) and are running Accumulo TServer processes. All the machines are connected via a 10Gb network and 3 of them are running ZooKeeper.

**Experiment:**

I am running heavy ingestion test on this cluster but I have never been able to reach more than 20% CPU usage on each Tablet Server. I am running an ingestion process (using batch writers) on each data node. The table is pre-split in order to have 4 tablets per tablet server. Monitoring the network I have seen that data is received/sent from each node with a peak rate of about 120MB/s / 100MB/s while the aggregated disk write throughput on each tablet servers is around 120MB/s.

**Accumulo Configuration:**

```
"table.file.replication": "2",
"table.compaction.minor.logs.threshold": "10",
"table.durability": "flush",
"table.file.max": "30",
"table.compaction.major.ratio": "9",
"table.split.threshold": "1G"

while the tablet server configuration is:
"tserver.wal.blocksize": "2G",
"tserver.walog.max.size": "8G",
"tserver.memory.maps.max": "32G",
"tserver.compaction.minor.concurrent.max": "50",
"tserver.compaction.major.concurrent.max": "8",
"tserver.total.mutation.queue.max": "50M",
"tserver.wal.replication": "2",
"tserver.compaction.major.thread.files.open.max": "15"

the tablet server heap has been set to 32GB
```

**Accumulo performance overview:**

[image: Screenshot from Accumulo management panel]

**Question:**

As you can see I have a lot of valleys in which the ingestion rate reaches 0. 
What would be a good procedure to identify the bottleneck which causes the 0 ingestion rate periods?
Thanks.

Comment: I would make the major compaction ratio a lot lower, like 1.5 or something, have a slightly higher tablet spit threshold around 2GB perhaps. You want your major compactions to happen evenly, at the moment they happen infrequently and a large number run. Is your ingest going to randomly insert into tablets, or mainly append do you think? You also want to look out for anything in the tserver logs around holding, thats a total performance killer.

Comment: The problem with major compacting infrequently is that you start to get a lot of files in the tablet server. If you go over the number set in `table.file.max` it will start doing a merging minor compaction, which is really bad: http://accumulo.apache.org/1.8/accumulo_user_manual.html#_compaction

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure that you are using the Accumulo native maps.
- Increase tserver.total.mutation.queue.max, I'd try 100M to 200M.
- Try using snappy compression (or none) instead of the default of gz.
- Make sure that accumulo.metadata and accumulo.root tables have a table.durability value of "flush" (I think you are already doing this). See https://accumulo.apache.org/blog/2016/11/02/durability-performance.html for an explanation of how to do this and why it matters.
- Try sharing your client code too. You can try to increase the number of BatchWriter threads and further pre-split the table.
- Verify that you have set the minor compaction log threshold, WAL max size, and native maps max size as per https://accumulo.apache.org/1.8/accumulo_user_manual.html#_native_maps_configuration

Comment: thx for the nice ideas, I tried all the things you suggested by have follow up questions about two of them. Regarding the native maps, my method of verification that they are indeed used is finding "tserver.memory.maps.native.enabled = true" in the logs, alsi I see "Allocated native map" and "Trying to load native map library" logs, is it enough to verify that? any regarding the compression, I have CPU utilization of ~30% using no compression will ease the CPU usage rather than accumulo right? what other impact it may have?

Comment: As long as you don't see an error after "trying to load native map library", then yes, that's sufficient. And yes, using different (or no) compression will reduce CPU utilization and increase performance. GZ is not multi-threaded, so even though you have available CPU on the system, that doesn't mean that isn't a bottleneck.

Comment: "GZ" is not multi threaded sounds like a really important conclusion! I will check it, really thx alot. the thing is that I really need compression! as far as I can tell snappy is not multi threaded also, is there a way to use a multi threaded compression (e.g. pigz). Thinking about it I ran test with several Tablet (up to 20) servers on same physical machine and the resources were still not fully utilized does this mean that the compression is not the bottleneck (it can be viewed as multithread)?

Comment: Yeah, don't read too much into compression algorithms not being multi-threaded. The way to parallelize things is to have more Tablets and tweak Accumulo configuration. Understanding where the system is spending time is more important when choosing configuration.